# How to transform and grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I would like to group by`contract date` by transforming `segment` referring to its `contract date` like below.

```
contractdate     segment  
～2020/2/1          a
2020/2/2～2020/4/1  b
2020/4/2～          c
```

My desired result is to cut `contractdate` into `segment` and `count`them into result tables.

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

my table is like below.

```
contractdate  status
2020/1/2        A 
2020/4/2        B 
2020/6/5        C
2020/1/2        C
2020/4/4        B
```

And here is my desired result.

```
segment     A   B   C
a           1   0   1
b           0   0   0
c           0   2   1
```

Comment: Whence is the source data for the `segment` column?

Comment: Please tag `RDBS` system you are using ?

Comment: it will be refering to following table `～2020/2/1:a
2020/2/2～2020/4/1:b
2020/4/2～:c` I updated question ,thanks

Comment: I use `oracle`. thanks

Comment: What is `~`? What is `:`? Are the two dates contract start and end?

Comment: how many statuscode is it, and what is the status codes? do you what the status codes as columns?

Comment: I am lost.  What is the input table?  What result do you want?  You seem to describe two inputs and one result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace missing bounds with sentinels (or replace notation with weird tilde character at all), then distribute contractdate of statuses into proper ranges:

```
with sg (contractdate,segment) as (
  select '~2020/2/1'        , 'a' from dual union all
  select '2020/2/2~2020/4/1', 'b' from dual union all
  select '2020/4/2~'        , 'c' from dual
), ssg as ( -- sanitized sg
  select coalesce(to_date(regexp_replace(contractdate,'([^~]*)~([^~]*)','\1'),'YYYY/MM/DD'), date '-4712-1-1')  as lowerbound  -- source: https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2008/01/what-is-the-lowest-and-highest-possible-date-in-oracle.html
       , coalesce(to_date(regexp_replace(contractdate,'([^~]*)~([^~]*)','\2'),'YYYY/MM/DD'), date '9999-01-01') as upperbound
       , segment
  from sg
), st (contractdate,status) as (
  select '2020/1/2', 'A' from dual union all
  select '2020/4/2', 'B' from dual union all
  select '2020/6/5', 'C' from dual union all
  select '2020/1/2', 'C' from dual union all
  select '2020/4/4', 'B' from dual
)
select segment
     , sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end)
     , sum(case when status = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)
     , sum(case when status = 'C' then 1 else 0 end)
from ssg left join st on to_date(st.contractdate,'YYYY/MM/DD') between ssg.lowerbound and ssg.upperbound
group by segment
order by segment
```

Please use CTE to specify your input data, not plaintext tables. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.